# npm install now failed OSX 10.8

Tags: node.js, osx-mountain-lion, npm

As title states I cannot install 'nowjs' with npm on my OSX ML 10.8.
Before to make anyone shout out :) I have xCode installed AND command line utilities.

These are lines from npm-log with error messages.

```
334 verbose true,/Volumes/Macintosh HD2/Library/Node/TestExpress/node_modules,/Volumes/Macintosh HD2/Library/Node/TestExpress/node_modules unbuild now@0.8.1
335 info postuninstall now@0.8.1
336 error node-proxy@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp configure build`
336 error `sh "-c" "node-gyp configure build"` failed with 1
337 error Failed at the node-proxy@0.6.0 install script.
337 error This is most likely a problem with the node-proxy package,
337 error not with npm itself.
337 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
337 error     node-gyp configure build
337 error You can get their info via:
337 error     npm owner ls node-proxy
337 error There is likely additional logging output above.
338 error System Darwin 12.2.0
339 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "now"
340 error cwd /Volumes/Macintosh HD2/Library/Node/TestExpress
341 error node -v v0.8.14
342 error npm -v 1.1.65
343 error code ELIFECYCLE
344 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone can point me to the righr direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes node-proxy (so in this case nowjs), needs to be installed with sudo.

Comment: yeahhh! Thank you! The silly thing is I also tried to execute npm as root (logging in as root), but it failed also. Executing with sudo worked perfectly. Thaks